# How to pass data from a text field through different children in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to pass some data obtained with a text field through several children, one inside the other, in a Flutter project. I've tried using `TextEditingController` but I found it difficult to go through all the children situated in different files. How can I do this?

I tried adding these few rows into the fist child:

```
TextEditingController idPicker =

  TextEditingController();
```

Comment: can you show us what u've done so far? (code)

Comment: @pedropimont I updated.

Comment: you can either pass this controller through the children constructors and access it inside of them or try a different state manage solution (like bloc). It's hard to help without more information, but try to pass it as arguments to the children via the constructors.

Comment: Riverpod!  Or some other state management system to allow data to be passed around in a manner other than parent to child constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question exactly but it may help you?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class MyDeliciousApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyDeliciousAppState createState() => _MyDeliciousAppState();
}

class _MyDeliciousAppState extends State<MyDeliciousApp> {

  String theText="";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(child: Column(children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter",hintText: "Enter your words"),
            onChanged: (b){
            setState(() {
              theText=b;
            });
            },
          ),
          Text(theText)
        ],),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```